# child nodes with multiple parents using xslt

Tags: xslt

The below is the original XML that I have, 
from this each asset and its parents need to be captured.

For e.g. Asset 002515 and it's parent and 002519 and it's parents

```
<businessobjects>
    <AssetID>
        <Code>002515</Code>
        <DependentAsset>
            <Code>002519</Code>
        </DependentAsset>
    </AssetID>
    <AssetID>
        <Code>002516</Code>
        <DependentAsset>
            <Code>002519</Code>
        </DependentAsset>
    </AssetID>
    <AssetID>
        <Code>002519</Code>
    </AssetID>
</businessobjects>
```

Desired Output:

```
    <businessobjects>
        <Assets>
             <Code>002519</Code>
             <Parent_Asset>002515</Parent_Asset>
             <Parent_Asset>002516</Parent_Asset>
        </Assets>
    </businessobjects>
```

XSLT Used:

```
<xsl:key name="Dependent" match="businessobjects/AssetID/DependentAsset"        use="AssetID/Code" />
<xsl:template match="/document">
<businessobjects>
<xsl:for-each select="businessobjects/AssetID">
<Assets>
<Code><xsl:value-of select="child::Code[1]"/></Code>
<Parent_Asset>
<xsl:value-of select="key('Dependent', Code)/../Code" />
</Parent_Asset>
</Assets>
</businessobjects>
```

Desired output is given, for Asset Code 002519 (since it has two parents and I'm able to get only one of them)

But with the above, I'm unable to get all the parent details for e.g. 002519 has two parents but I'm able to get only one. Can someone help how to get two parents.

Comment: This is a *grouping* issue before it can become anything else (since you want to consolidate the multiple occurrences of DependentAsset). Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: but what is the xslt code that is missing in my XSLT file??

Comment: Please answer my question first.

Comment: Yes, I can use XSLT 2.0

Comment: I am sorry, I misread your input. No grouping is required, provided that each `DependentAsset` is also listed as an `AssetID` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="parent" match="AssetID" use="DependentAsset/Code" />

<xsl:template match="/businessobjects">
    <businessobjects>
        <xsl:for-each select="AssetID">
            <Assets>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Code"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('parent', Code)">
                    <Parent_Asset>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>
                    </Parent_Asset>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Assets>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </businessobjects>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<businessobjects>
   <Assets>
      <Code>002515</Code>
   </Assets>
   <Assets>
      <Code>002516</Code>
   </Assets>
   <Assets>
      <Code>002519</Code>
      <Parent_Asset>002515</Parent_Asset>
      <Parent_Asset>002516</Parent_Asset>
   </Assets>
</businessobjects>
```

Note that this assumes every `DependentAsset` has also an individual (and unique) entry as an `AssetID`.

Comment: I tried with the below.  <xsl:key name="parent" match="AssetID/DependentAsset" use="Code" /> and you have used <xsl:key name="parent" match="AssetID" use="DependentAsset/Code" />,      what is the difference, I could not make out.

Comment: @SSN My key retrieves parents by the code of their children; your key retrieves children by their own code.